# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency when dependency is a function of another hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm writing a web application that fetches data.

```
const { data, count, error, isLoading, setEnabled: loadData } = useData();

useEffect(() => {
    loadData(true);
}, []);
```

```
const useData = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [rows, setRows] = useState<Row[]>([]);
    const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
    const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const isCancelled = useRef(false);
    const data = useMemo(() => rows, [rows]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCount(data ? data.length : 0);
    }, [data]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                fethFunction();
            } catch (error) {
                const e = error as Error;
                setError(e.message);
            } finally {
                setIsLoading(false);
                setIsFetching(false);
            }
        };

        isCancelled.current = !enabled;
        if (enabled) fetchData();
    }, [enabled, data, error]);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            isCancelled.current = true;
        };
    }, []);

    return { data, count, error, isLoading, setEnabled };
};

export default useData;
```

The code linter asks me to add loadData to useEffect dependency array but if I do that I trigger an infinite loop. How do I correctly organize this?

FYI I also have a router enabled which is why the loop triggers.

Comment: you can add it in the dependency array and wrap load data with a useCallback

Comment: you have mismatching brackets. There's something wrong with your code, somewhere around `const fetchData = async () => {` and the `catch` without `try`

Comment: @thomas Was just a copy / paste error, thanks :)

Comment: @nullptr I have tried that but it still triggers an infinite loop

Comment: what about @tanstack/query? I see you have a lot of states, instead you can use react query

Comment: what `setEnabled` does in `useData`? not sure if you can update a state in custom hook. normally we use custom hook return read-only values or just update state inside custom hook.

Comment: I replicated this, I dont see any infinite loop. https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-dream-fhs5c5?file=/src/App.js Where's the issue? Share a sandbox link for us to look into.

Comment: @rachitiitr he is working on typescript

Comment: checkout this , it may help https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/react-hook-useeffect-has-a-missing-dependency/

Comment: How does that matter if its typescript or javascript in regards to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error a lot. If you can't move the function into the hook (which does not appear to be possible here) then you need to go for the `useCallback` option as noted or change your linter.

Currently my eslint config has these values:

```
{
  ...
  "rules": {
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error", // Checks rules of Hooks
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": [
      "warn",
    ],
  }
}
```

Another option might be to pass a boolean into your `useData(enabled)` hook.  So that you can trigger when you want it to load data or not.